# IndexOutOfBounds error in ArrayList sort function

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I am currently trying to make a program to sort an integer array list without using any API. I have searched similar questions and found that the problem is mainly with the loop, but I am unable to find that problem in my code.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

class Distro {
    public static ArrayList<Integer> max_out(ArrayList<Integer>list) {
        ArrayList<Integer>it = new ArrayList<Integer>();            
        final int initial_size = list.size();
        for(int i = 0;i<initial_size;i++) {
            int maxo = Collections.max(list);
            it.add(maxo);
            list.remove(maxo);
        }
        return(it);
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 43, Size:3
>   at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
>   at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:492)
>   at Distro.max_out(Grown.java:10)at Grown.main(Grown.java:22)*

Comment: you are removing from list while iterating on its size. Guess what, removing an element reduces the size.... so the exception. Also not a good idea to alter the list while iterating on it using for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it out and the issue is not with your logic as even though you are iterating list.size() times, you are not actually iterating over the list itself.

The issue with your code is that you define maxo as int and not Integer. Due to which list.remove(int x) method is called where x is index of element. If you defined maxo as Integer, list.remove(Object o) would be called, removing the maxo value which is what you originally wanted to do.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(2);
list.add(-1);
list.add(4);
ArrayList<Integer> it = new ArrayList<Integer>();
final int initial_size = list.size();
for(int i = 0;i<initial_size;i++) {
    Integer maxo = Collections.max(list);
    it.add(maxo);
    list.remove(maxo);
}
System.out.println(it);
```

Output:

```
[4, 2, -1]
```

Comment: According to API `remove()` takes an `int`, so using `Integer` is not a factor `public E remove(int index)

Removes the element at the specified position in this list. Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices).`

Comment: from documentation

E remove(int index)
Removes the element at the specified position in this list.
boolean remove(Object o)
Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present.

Comment: So then why is using `int` instead of `Integer` a problem then? It says right there `int index` is the parameter

Comment: using int is causing problem because Collections never store primitives. So he is fetching the max value and trying to remove it from list. But since it is stored as int, the method remove(int x) is being called which considers x as index. If he stores it as Integer, the method remove(Object o) will be called removing max element from list

Comment: Oh ok, got it. You're right. I'd recommend making that clear in the answer

Answer (score 1):

The maximum index of an array will be one less than the size, so you need minus one to find last element.
This is consistent with your `IndexOutOfBoundsException` error.

Fix should be `list.remove(maxo - 1)`

Comment: list.remove() takes the object to remove as parameter and not the index. Hence your answer is incorrect.

public boolean remove(Object o)

Comment: No, you're wrong. ArrayList remove() can also take an int as index, hence the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` exception https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-int-

Comment: Agreed.. my bad. I wanted to remove my downvote but the post went missing. Its an overloaded method and that is actually what was causing the issue for him.

Comment: No prob. I wasn't sure and deleted the answer, but then double-checked. You can remove downvote now

Comment: I will remove my downvote but you need to edit the post a little. its locked until you edit the solution. Sorry!

Comment: Ok, made an edit. I downvoted your answer because it's not correct to say the problem is caused by passing `int` instead of `Integer`.

Comment: It actually is and I tested it. Plus remove is an overloaded method. You can check Arraylist documentation

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't want to use any API (because you're using the `Collections.max()`), you may do something like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Sorting{
    public static void main(String[] args){
      // create an array example
      List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
      // populate it in ascending order
      for(int i=0 ; i<10; i++){
          list.add(i);
      }
      // check its content BEFORE sorting
      System.out.println(list);
      // sort it
      max_out(list);
      // check its content AFTER sorting
      System.out.println(list);
    }

    public static void max_out(List<Integer> list) {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < list.size(); i++){
           for(int j = 0 ; j < list.size() - i - 1; j++){
               if (list.get(j) < list.get(j+1)){ // move to left if it's bigger 
                   int swap  = list.get(j);
                   list.set(j, list.get(j+1));
                   list.set(j+1, swap);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Test**

```
Before [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
After  [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Furthermore, regarding your approach, it works for me, but I think the problem is in the `remove()` method which has two versions (*overloaded methods*):

- `E remove(int index)`: which removes the element at the specified **position** in this list.
- `boolean remove(Object o)`: which removes the first occurrence of the specified **element** from this list.

And because `int maxo`in your `for-loop` is a primitive type, so the compiler will think you're asking for the *first* method.

What you can do, is either changing `int maxo` into object type `Integer`, or using `int indexOf(Object o)` method which returns the **index** of the first occurrence of the specified **element** in this list, like this:

```
list.remove(list.indexOf(maxo));
```

Answer (score -1):

Ofcourse this will cause an error.

**Reason 1:** You are removing elements from your main list, and at the same time iterating it to till the maximum size which you stored earlier in your final variable. At some point in iteration, it will cause an error.

**Reason 2:** You are removing an element from your main list, at the index defined by your `maxo` variable, which contains a maximum element, not an index value.

Resolution is keep track of size of the list, and remove the index value only.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> max_out(ArrayList<Integer>list) {
    ArrayList<Integer> it = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i= 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        int maxo = Collections.max(list);
        it.add(maxo);
        list.remove(list.indexOf(maxo);
    }
    return it;
}
```

Comment: why are you giving a -1 to every answer here? please go check your question first, my solution is correct.. I am downvoting your question.

Comment: I am not the downvoter but take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html. `remove()` works with the `Object` not only index

Comment: Yes, that was my downvote because `remove()` can also take an `int` index, not just element

Comment: but you cannot remove a primitive type from it like that.

Comment: @MrJLP, thats what i removed as index only, using int type. If you remove an int value, it will assume as an index.